# SIGSEGV when loading vector file with QgsVectorLayer class, yet ogrinfo looks valid?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, linux, qgsvectorlayer

I have a program set up as part of a QT application written in C++ to overlay data on a KDE Marble map, and am using the C++ API from QGIS to achieve this.  I create the vector file as a GeoJSON by launching a Python program using the `QProcess` class.  When I try to load the file as a vector layer, I get a segmentation fault error.  The line of code is:

```
const QString layer_name = "My Data";
const QString provider = "ogr";
QgsVectorLayer *vl = new QgsVectorLayer(file_path,layer_name,provider);
```

and the fatal returned to me according to GDB is from the internal function call:

```
QgsOgrProvider::getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest const&) const()
```

and that's as far as the backtrace I have goes. Since I use Python to make the conversion into the JSON file and QGIS uses GDAL as the OGR provider, I check from the command line (Fedora Linux, V28) and I get no errors:

```
INFO: Open of `gdf.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: gdf
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-83.475586, 21.579536) - (-83.475586, 21.579536)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Geometry Column = _ogr_geometry_
U: Real (0.0)
V: Real (0.0)
T: Real (0.0)
P: Real (0.0)
spd: Real (0.0)
lon: Real (0.0)
lat: Real (0.0)
Time: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(gdf):96
  U (Real) = -9.57712459564209
  V (Real) = 7.50930976867676
  T (Real) = 21.077033996582
  P (Real) = 903.073608398438
  spd (Real) = 12.4758520126343
  lon (Real) = -83.4755859375
  lat (Real) = 21.5795364379883
  Time (String) = 2020-10-01_12:00:00
  POINT (-83.4755859375 21.5795364379883)
```

I'm not sure if maybe one of the features is invalid and is throwing it off or not as it's a large file (probably 100,000 point geometries; working on a GRASS application to make them into polygons and fix self-intersections and the like to make it more portable and easier to debug).  I've tried using rasters and meshes but I get other issues come up (the raster/mesh is from a NetCDF that I create from NCL).  I have the needed header files included in the C++ files, and my `main.cpp` initiates a `QgsApplication`:

```
QgsApplication b(argc, argv, true);
QString qgis_pfx = "/home/my_user/qgis";
b.setPrefixPath(qgis_pfx,true);
b.initQgis();
```

If anyone has any suggestions or needs to see more example code let me know.  I am using QT 5.11.3 with QGIS 3.8 and the Python version is 3.6.  Unfortunately most of the newer versions I have to build from source; upgrading to a newer Fedora OS is out of my hands.

EDIT: also I should add that when loading the file using the QGIS GUI, it works:
[image]